# Regex for matching character after odd brace

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace `a\nb` with `a\\nb` to make below string a valid json.
It is known that there are odd count of `'` characters before desired `a\n`
What could be a regex for this?

```
{
    'key1': 'a
b',
    'key2':'value2',
    'key3':'value3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `replaceAll()`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{
            'key1': 'a
            b',
            'key2':'value2',
            'key3':'value3'
            }";
        str = str.replaceAll("a\nb", "a\\nb");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Edit: changed `replaceAll("\n", "\\n")` to `replaceAll("a\nb", "a\\nb")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried this and it replaced all other line breaks with `\\n` which broke json

Comment: String.replaceAll() IS regex